# What series are these villains in this GPF comic from?

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

[This *General Protection Fault* comic](http://www.gpf-comics.com/archive/2015/12/21) has *the* sci-fi geek character rattling off a list of science fiction villains:

[image]

> I *will* help find the Earth, and *nothing* can stop me. Not even Martians, Klingons, Cylons, Daleks, Sith, Draconians, Kromaggs, Xenomorphs, Terminators, Vogons, Replicants...

and this message in the References box:

> References: No reference links this time, folks. But I do challenge you to name as many of the sci-fi properties as you can whose villains are referenced in Panel Three! (Premium subscribers can get the answers in the Author's Notes!)

I'm not a premium subscriber, so I can't just go look at the answers. But I *was* able to identify half of them.

- Martians - *War of the Worlds*
- Klingons - *Star Trek*
- Cylons
- Daleks - *Doctor Who*
- Sith - *Star Wars*
- Draconians
- Kromaggs
- Xenomorphs - *Alien*
- Terminators - *Terminator*
- Vogons
- Replicants

What series are the other ones from?

Comment: Draconians are from Doctor Who.

Comment: Is there anything on this list that couldn't be answered by a basic Google search? (I'm tempted to downvote on "does not show any research effort" ground from DV arrow, but will refrain if someone shows me a positive answer to that non-rhethorical question)

Comment: @DVK: I thought about that. My justification would be that Stack Exchange sites *are* useful for gathering particular information into one place. Perhaps not a particularly *strong* one...

Comment: @DVK You are demonstrably correct (although I only had to look up Kromaggs)

Comment: Ah, screw it. I am, after all, on strike, and I used to love GPF. No DV :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Martians are from lots of different things. *War of the Worlds* is referenced in the question, but *A Princess of Mars* also springs to mind, among [myriad of other examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian). Which one the artist was referring to can only be learned from the author notes
- The Cylons are the principal antagonists of *Battlestar Galactica*

  [image]
- "Draconians" could refer to one of two fictional creatures:

  - *Doctor Who* had Draconians, an intergalactic empire of humanoid reptiles appearing in ["Frontier in Space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_in_Space), a Third Doctor story:

    [image]
  - More likely (since we've already had a *Doctor Who* alien mentioned) are the Draconians from the *Dragonlance* universe, a popular *Dungeons & Dragons* campaign setting that spawned a novel series<sup>1</sup>:

    [image]
- Kromaggs are from the late 90's TV show *Sliders*

  [image]
- Vogons are from *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, renowned for producing the third-worst poetry in the universe

  [image]

  The above image is from the 2005 live action adaptation starring Martin Freeman
- Replicants are the androids from *Blade Runner*. Harrison Ford's character, Deckard, hunts runaway Replicants for a living

---

<sup>1</sup> Not to Adeptus for pointing this out

Comment: Though probably not relevant, Draconians are *also* from the Dragonlance D&D setting (games, books, etc)

Comment: @Adeptus Cheers; added that in. Honestly I stopped Googling for "Draconians" when I hit the reptilian conspiracies. Didn't take long